# Unable to retrieve serial number read phone state of emulator

Tags: android

Is there any way to have the emulator return a serial number as shown in the following snippet :

```
final String deviceId = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId();
if (deviceId != null) {
    return deviceId;
} else {
    return android.os.Build.SERIAL;
}
```

Comment: yes but its always the same number for the emulator

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
String android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

ANDROID_ID is a 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated when the user first sets up the device and should remain constant for the lifetime of the user's device. The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.